# "re-starting" a loop after adding items to an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsmutablearray, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code to simulate a process flow in my laboratory. Whereby a timer adds new items to a NSMutablearray. How do I get the while [array count] !=0 loop to recognise the new additions?

Or is there a better methodology?

I'm using GCD blocks to simulate a parallel process. The HEFTBooker object just takes a sample number and then waits a defined time period before "marking" itself as free to process another sample.

```
-(void)runBookingIn:(id)sender  {
    HEFTLaboratoryUnit *__labUnit = [[HEFTLaboratoryUnit alloc]init];
    self.labUnit = __labUnit;

    NSMutableArray *sampleNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Speed factor speeds up time for modelling i.e. 10 = 10 x normal time.
    NSInteger speedFactor = 10;    
    // Sample arrival rate into laboratory per hour
    NSInteger sampleArrivalRate = 50;

    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    self.timer = [RNTimer repeatingTimerWithTimeInterval:sampleArrivalRate/speedFactor         block:^{
        [weakSelf addNewSamplesToQueue];
    }];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        [sampleNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }

    self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn = sampleNumbers;

    NSMutableArray *bookerIns = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    HEFTBookerIn *webster = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
    webster.bookingInRate = 60;
    webster.name=@"Webster";
    [bookerIns addObject:webster];

    HEFTBookerIn *duffy = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
    duffy.bookingInRate = 30;
    duffy.name=@"Duffy";
    [bookerIns addObject:duffy];

    HEFTBookerIn *marrington = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
    marrington.bookingInRate = 40;
    marrington.name=@"Marrington";
    [bookerIns addObject:marrington];

    HEFTBookerIn *chatha = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
    chatha.bookingInRate = 10;
    chatha.name=@"Kam";
    [bookerIns addObject:chatha];

    int i = 0;
    long countSamples;

    countSamples = [self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn count];
    // loop sample numbers
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.HEFT.BookerQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_queue_t arrivalsQueue;
    arrivalsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.HEFT.ArrivalsQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    while ([self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn count] != 0 )
    {
        NSInteger sampleNo = [[self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
        long count = [bookerIns count];
        int counter = 0;

        //loop over booker ins
        int j;
        for (j=0; j <count ; j++) {
            HEFTBookerIn *booker = [bookerIns objectAtIndex:counter];

            if (booker.free == YES){
                dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                    [booker bookingIn:sampleNo :speedFactor];
                    [self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                });
                break;
            }
            else{
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }
}


-(void) addNewSamplesToQueue{
    NSLog(@"More Samples Arriving");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        [self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [NSMutableArray is not thread safe](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)

Comment: And that double underscores are reserved for compiler keywords.

Comment: Thanks, so I think I have to come up with a different methodology

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, and made mutable array addition thread safe with the addition of locks.

```
-(void)runBookingIn:(id)sender  {

    HEFTLaboratoryUnit *_labUnit = [[HEFTLaboratoryUnit alloc]init];
    self.labUnit = _labUnit;

    labUnit.booking_in_lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Speed factor speeds up time for modelling i.e. 10 = 10 x normal time.
    NSInteger speedFactor = 10;

    // Sample arrival rate into laboratory per hour
    NSInteger sampleArrivalRate = 50;

    __weak id weakSelf = self;

    // Add initial samples
    [self addNewSamplesToQueue:10];


    // Set timer going for further samples
    self.timer = [RNTimer repeatingTimerWithTimeInterval:sampleArrivalRate/speedFactor   block:^{
        [weakSelf addNewSamplesToQueue:10];
   }];


   // Init booker in Units
   NSMutableArray *bookerIns = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   HEFTBookerIn *webster = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
   webster.bookingInRate = 60;
   webster.name=@"Webster";
   [bookerIns addObject:webster];

   HEFTBookerIn *duffy = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
   duffy.bookingInRate = 30;
   duffy.name=@"Duffy";
   [bookerIns addObject:duffy];

   HEFTBookerIn *marrington = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
   marrington.bookingInRate = 40;
   marrington.name=@"Marrington";
   [bookerIns addObject:marrington];

   HEFTBookerIn *chatha = [[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init];
   chatha.bookingInRate = 10;
   chatha.name=@"Kam";
   [bookerIns addObject:chatha];


   // create arrivals and processing loops
   dispatch_queue_t processingQueue;
   processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.HEFT.BookerQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

   dispatch_queue_t arrivalsQueue;
   arrivalsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.HEFT.ArrivalsQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

  // Set timer going for further samples
  self.timer2 = [RNTimer repeatingTimerWithTimeInterval:sampleArrivalRate/speedFactor        block:^{
    [self bookingLoop:arrivalsQueue processingQ:processingQueue bookerInUnits:bookerIns    speed:speedFactor];
   }];
```

}

```
- (void)bookingLoop:(dispatch_queue_t)arrivalsQueue processingQ:(dispatch_queue_t)processingQueue bookerInUnits: (NSMutableArray *)bookerIns speed:(NSInteger)speed{
    int i = 0;
    long countSamples;

     countSamples = [labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn count];

     dispatch_sync(arrivalsQueue, ^{
       while ([self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn count] != 0 )
       {
            NSInteger sampleNo = [[self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];

        long count = [bookerIns count];
        int counter = 0;

        //loop over booker ins

        int j;

        for (j=0; j <count ; j++) {
            HEFTBookerIn *booker = [bookerIns objectAtIndex:counter];
                 if (booker.free == YES){
                    dispatch_sync(processingQueue, ^{
                        [booker bookingIn:sampleNo :speed];
                        [self.labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn removeObjectAtIndex:i];
                    });
                    break;
               }
               else{
                   counter ++;
               }

           }
        }
    });
```

}

```
-(void) addNewSamplesToQueue:(NSInteger) noSamplesToAdd{

    NSLog(@"More Samples Arriving %ld", noSamplesToAdd);
    [self.labUnit.booking_in_lock lock];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       [labUnit.samplesToBeBookedIn addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
    }
   [self.labUnit.booking_in_lock unlock];
```

}